# Annotation text size changes when reopening QGIS files. How to fix?

Tags: qgis, qgis-3

I am currently using version 3.22.9 but the issue has been ongoing for years, over several updates. When I make a map document, and annotate with text boxes (Text Annotations), the size of the text changes when I reopen the document after closing it. I then need to manually change the text size of all the text boxes to fit properly again.

Does anyone know of a fix for this?

Comment: If you talk about HTML text boxes in QGIS composer (sized via CSS), this could help: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/346398/inconsistent-display-of-html-table-font-size-in-qgis-layouts/346413#346413

Comment: Thanks Christoph. I'll take a look.