# QGIS layout template font appearance

Tags: qgis, print-composer, font

I've made a layout template in QGIS 3.26.2-Buenos Aires. When my colleague opens the layout on their PC the font appearance seems to have reverted to default. This is happening for text and dynamic text, but the table frame and legend are fine.

This is how it looks on my PC:

[image]

On my collegues PC, the font appears like this using the template:

[image]

Comment: Maybe this answers your question: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/346398/inconsistent-display-of-html-table-font-size-in-qgis-layouts/346413#346413

Comment: Probably because yours collegues are on QGIS 3.22… I have the same problem! I had to update all the computers of the company to the last LTR (3.28) to avoid such a problem!

Comment: I have the same problem, I create a Layout template and when my colleague open it, the text doesn't have the same Font and Size as the template. We are using the same QGIS version and we are not working with HTML Objects.